# Javascript: using tuples as dictionary keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary, tuples

I have a situation where I want to create a mapping from a tuple to an integer. In python, I would simply use a tuple `(a,b)` as the key to a dictionary,

Does Javascript have tuples? I found that `(a,b)` in javascript as an expression just returns b (the last item). Apparently this is inherited from C.

So, as a workaround, I thought I can use arrays instead,

```
my_map[[a,b]] = c
```

I tried it at the Firebug console and it seemed to work. Is that a good way to do it?

Another alternative I thought of is to create a string out of the tuples

```
my_map[""+a+":"+b] = c
```

So the question is: is there any problem with any of these methods? Is there a better way?

#### EDIT:

Small clarification: in my case, a,b,c are all integers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EcmaScript doesn't distinguish between indexing a property by name or by `[]`, eg.

```
a.name
```

is literally equivalent to

```
a["name"]
```

The only difference is that numbers, etc are not valid syntax in a named property access

```
a.1
a.true
```

and so on are all invalid syntax.

Alas the reason all of these indexing mechanisms are the same is because in EcmaScript *all* property names are strings.  eg.

```
a[1]
```

is effectively interpreted as

```
a[String(1)]
```

Which means in your example you do:

```
my_map[[a,b]] = c
```

Which becomes

```
my_map[String([a,b])] = c
```

Which is essentially the same as what your second example is doing (depending on implementation it may be faster however).

If you want true value-associative lookups you will need to implement it yourself on top of the js language, and you'll lose the nice [] style access :-(

Comment: While technically correct, I would like to warn against actually using the syntax `a[1]` as it looks too much like array dereferencing and if the object in question is actually an instance of `Array` then you'd shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Guss sorry can you explain it better? I'm new to the language js and i haven't got your point

Comment: I'm just saying that people shouldn't use numbers as property references unless they specifically mean to access array members by index. Otherwise, the code is hard to understand and confusing. Example:
`var objA = { "1": "abc", "3": "def" };`
vs.
`var objA = [ "abc", undefined, "def" ];`
?
Both answer to `objA[1]` and `obj[3]` the same, but only one is really an array with array fields such as `push()` and `length`

Answer (score 7):

You could use my [jshashtable](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable) and then use any object as a key, though **assuming your tuples are arrays of integers** I think your best bet is one you've mentioned yourself: use the `join()` method of Array to create property names of a regular object. You could wrap this very simply:

```
function TupleDictionary() {
 this.dict = {};
}

TupleDictionary.prototype = {
 tupleToString: function(tuple) {
  return tuple.join(",");
 },

 put: function(tuple, val) {
  this.dict[ this.tupleToString(tuple) ] = val;
 },

 get: function(tuple) {
  return this.dict[ this.tupleToString(tuple) ];
 }
};

var dict = new TupleDictionary();
dict.put( [1,2], "banana" );
alert( dict.get( [1,2] ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

All object keys in Javascript are strings. Using `my_map[[a,b]] = c` will produce a key in `my_map` which is the result of `[a,b].toString()`: `a.toString() + ',' + b.toString()`. This may actually be desirable (and is similar to your use of `a + ':' + b`), but you may run into conflicts if your keys contain the separator (either the comma if you use the array as the key, or the colon if you write the string as you have in your example).

Edit: An alternate approach would be to keep a separate array for key references. Eg:

```
var keys = [
    [a,b],
    [c,d]
];
var my_map = {
    'keys[0]': /* Whatever [a,b] ought to be the key for */,
    'keys[1]': /* Whatever [c,d] ought to be the key for */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the most simple and "natural" way to achieve something similar is by using multidimensional arrays, like this:

```
var my_map = [["blah","blah","bla"],
              ["foo", "bla", 8],
              [324, 2345, 235],
              [true, false, "whatever..."]];
```